# ConcurrentBag Skiping some items C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I am using concurrentbag for scraping URLs , Right now its working fine for 500 / 100 urls but when I am trying to scrape 8000 urls . All URLs not processing and some items pending in inputQueue.

But I am using  while (!inputQueue.IsEmpty) . So, it should run loop till any items exists into inputqueue.

I want only run 100 threads max. So, I first creating 100 threads and calling "Run()" method and inside that method I am running a loop to take items till items exits in inputqueue and add into output queue after scraping urls.

```
public ConcurrentBag<Data> inputQueue = new ConcurrentBag<Data>();
    public ConcurrentBag<Data> outPutQueue = new ConcurrentBag<Data>();

    public List<Data> Scrapes(List<Data> scrapeRequests)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        string proxy_session_id = new Random().Next().ToString();

        numberOfRequestSent = 0;

        watch.Start();

        foreach (var sRequest in scrapeRequests)
        {
            inputQueue.Add(sRequest);
        }
        //inputQueue.CompleteAdding();

        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < n_parallel_exit_nodes; i++) //create 100 threads only
        {
            taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
               await Run();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());   //Waiting

        //print result
        Console.WriteLine("Number Of URLs Found - {0}", scrapeRequests.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Number Of Request Sent - {0}", numberOfRequestSent);

        Console.WriteLine("Input Queue - {0}", inputQueue.Count);

        Console.WriteLine("OutPut Queue - {0}", outPutQueue.ToList().Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Success - {0}", outPutQueue.ToList().Where(x=>x.IsProxySuccess==true).Count().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Failed - {0}", outPutQueue.ToList().Where(x => x.IsProxySuccess == false).Count().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Process Time In - {0}", watch.Elapsed);

        return outPutQueue.ToList();
    }


    async Task<string> Run()
    {
        while (!inputQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            var client = new Client(super_proxy_ip, "US");

            if (!client.have_good_super_proxy())
                client.switch_session_id();
            if (client.n_req_for_exit_node == switch_ip_every_n_req)
                client.switch_session_id();

            var scrapeRequest = new ProductResearch_ProData();
            inputQueue.TryTake(out scrapeRequest);

            try
            {
                numberOfRequestSent++;

                // Console.WriteLine("Sending request for - {0}", scrapeRequest.URL);
                scrapeRequest.HTML = client.DownloadString((string)scrapeRequest.URL);
                //Console.WriteLine("Response done for - {0}", scrapeRequest.URL);

                scrapeRequest.IsProxySuccess = true;

                outPutQueue.Add(scrapeRequest); //add object to output queue

                //lumanti code
                client.handle_response();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");

                scrapeRequest.IsProxySuccess = false;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                outPutQueue.Add(scrapeRequest); //add object to output queue

                //lumanti code
                client.handle_response(e);
            }

            client.clean_connection_pool();
            client.Dispose();
        }

        return await Task.Run(() => "Done");
    }
```

Comment: Why the `return await Task.Run(() => "Done");`?

Comment: @canton7 I think I can't return void, So, using it, It will effect ?

Comment: It does nothing useful. Your `Run` method is synchronous. Just make it non-async, and make it return `string`. (You could make it asynchronous, but then you'd have to use an async `DownloadString` method, and await it. You'd also have to use `Task.Run` rather than `Task.Factory.StartNew`, as `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't have an overload which accepts a `Func<Task>`: this is a problem in your code at the moment, but it's cancelled out by the fact that your `Run` method is synchronously, currently)

Comment: You have a race condition - the task consuming the input queue will exit when the queue becomes empty, so if it's running faster than the producer, it will exit too early.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I thought that, but the producer does not run in parallel. All items to be processed are in `inputQueue` at the point that the first consumer starts

Comment: @MatthewWatson Any Suggestion ?

Comment: @canton7 Hmm yes, you're right. But now I suspect the code in the question and the actual code might be different...

Comment: @Deepak For starters, 100 threads is way too many. In general, you shouldn't be using more threads than there are processor cores.

Comment: (Note that these threads spend most of their time sleeping, waiting for web requests to come back, so having more than there are cores isn't necessarily a bad thing)

Comment: Not much error checking going on here, nor any timeouts. Bulk downloading can do strange things between you and the internet. There are many possible failure points in the chain of routers and switches leading to the backbone. As you dial up the numbers, you'll see more and more stalled downloads. You need to deal with these effectively through the use of timeouts and so on.

Comment: @canton7 Each thread has a LOT of overhead, and being in use makes the threadpool expand a lot. It's definitely bad to have idle threads.

Comment: Yes. There's no reason not to go *properly* async with this code. [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) can really help with constraining the concurrency in an effective way, such that the threadpool can idle its way through a high volume of connections.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Right, but if you're downloading synchronously it's the *only* way to get multiple downloads happening in parallel. Yes you use a bit more memory, but you probably won't get that much contention. I've run up to 10k threads in this sort of model (legacy libs, don't ask) and things are "fine". Threads aren't *that* expensive

Comment: Agreed, DataFlow / LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler + proper async/await is a better way to go, though.

Comment: @canton7 Well, there's a significant delay between each new thread starting once you've surpassed `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()` - which is 8 on my system.

Comment: @MatthewWatson 2 a second, typically

Comment: You should be able to run many many connections using the async APIs without any sort of ThreadPool bloat at all. If your ThreadPool is spawning additional threads when dealing with network stuff, its a huge hint that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here, but none of them seems to be the cause for the `inputQueue.Count` having a none-zero value at the end. In any case I would like to point at the problems I can see.

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();
for (var i = 0; i < n_parallel_exit_nodes; i++) // create 100 threads only
{
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Run();
    }, TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously));
}
```

The method [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) doesn't understand async delegates, so when it is called with an async lambda as argument it returns a nested task. In this case it returns a `Task<Task<string>>`. You store this nested task in `List<Task>` collection, which is possible because the type [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) inherits from the type `Task`, but doing so you lose the ability to await for the completion (and get the result) of the inner task. You only hold a reference to the outer task. Miraculously this is not a problem in this case (it usually is) since the outer task does all the work, and the inner task does essentially nothing (other than using a thread-pool thread to return a `"Done"` string that is not really needed anywhere).

You also don't attach any continuations to the outer tasks, so the flag `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` seems redundant.

```
// create 100 threads only
```

You don't create 100 threads, you create 100 tasks. These tasks are scheduled in the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), which will be immediately starved because the tasks are long-running, and will start injecting one new thread every 500 msec until all scheduled tasks have been assigned to a thread.

```
var scrapeRequest = new ProductResearch_ProData();
inputQueue.TryTake(out scrapeRequest);
```

Here you instantiate an object of type `ProductResearch_ProData` that is immediately discarded and becomes eligible for garbage collection in the very next line. The [`TryTake`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1.trytake) method will either return an object removed from the bag, or `null` if the bag is empty. You ignore the return value of the `TryTake` method, which is entirely possible to be `false` because meanwhile the bag may have been emptied by another worker, and then proceed with a `scrapeRequest` that has possibly a null value, resulting in that case to a `NullReferenceException`.

Worth noting that you extract an object of type `ProductResearch_ProData` from a `ConcurrentBag<Data>`, so either the class `Data` inherits from
the base class `ProductResearch_ProData`, or there is a transcription error in the code.